# Must Tight binding model use real space Basis?

Tags: tight-binding

To construct a tight binding model, the basis must be real space?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't have to be. It just won't be obviously recognizable as a tight-binding model in Fourier space, e.g.